# Snowflake - date constant/literal for ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to define constant/date literal that will work with `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN`?

According to documentation:

> [Date and Time Constants](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date-and-time-constants)
>
> **Constants (also known as literals) refers to fixed data values.** Snowflake supports using string constants to specify fixed date, time, or timestamp values. String constants must always be enclosed between delimiter characters. Snowflake supports using single quotes to delimit string constants.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> date '2010-09-14'
> ```

and

> [Table Column Actions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table.html#table-column-actions-tablecolumnaction)
>
> ```
>   ADD COLUMN col_name col_data_type [ DEFAULT | AUTOINCREMENT ... ] [ inlineConstraint ] [, ...]
> ```
>
> Adds a new column, including optionally adding a default and/or inline constraint for the column, to the table:  For additional details about column defaults, see [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#create-table)
>
> ...
>
> ```
> DEFAULT <expr>
> ```
>
> Column default value is defined by the specified expression which can be any of the following:
>
> - **Constant value.**
> - Simple expression
> - Sequence reference (seq_name.NEXTVAL)

For an existing table t:

```
CREATE TABLE t(d DATE);
INSERT INTO t(d) VALUES ('2000-01-01');

SELECT * FROM t;
-- D
-- 2000-01-01

-- addding new columns with default value works fine for these data types
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN d2 INT DEFAULT 1;
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN d3 STRING DEFAULT 'some string';
```

Let's try to add new date column with default value attached:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN d1 DATE DEFAULT '2000-01-01';
-- SQL compilation error: Default value data type does not match data type for column D1

ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN d1 DATE DEFAULT '2000-01-01'::DATE;
-- SQL compilation error: Invalid column default expression [CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE)]

ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN d1 DATE DEFAULT date '2000-01-01';
-- SQL compilation error: Invalid column default expression [CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE)]

-- default value during creation is possible
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(d DATE DEFAULT date '2000-01-01');
```

It seems that `date '2000-01-01'`,which should be date literal, is treated as expression `[CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATE)]` that is not a simple one.
It works in context of CREATE TABLE but not in context of ALTER TABLE.

Is there is a way to provide contstant/simple expression that will work with `ALTER TABLE` for DATE column?

Comment: if it works on `CREATE TABLE` but not on `ALTER TABLE` it sounds like a bug, I would report to support. It may be the difference between on create the value is inserted as compared to ALTERS are after the fact, thus what existing NULLs get mapped to.. but in that case you could just create a new table with the default, and insert from the old table, and then swap them. (as long as your live process that is injecting into said table has been paused).

Comment: I do not believe this is a bug as much as it is actually documented as a limitation of the ADD COLUMN option.  In the usage notes, it makes note that expressions are not currently supported in the default setting, which a cast is considered.  This is inconvenient, so should be noted to Snowflake as such.  However, creating a new table from the original table is very straight-forward as @SimeonPilgrim has suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround using update statement:

Create the column_name with timestamp datatype

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name DATE;
```

Since the newly create column will be null, you could update it:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = cast('2022-01-01' as DATE) WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```

Comment: This approach(ADD COLUMN + UPDATE) does not solve the case. The DEFAULT property is not setup at the table level so for every new row afterwards it is still not be set.

Answer (score 0):

The below statement will work to set default low and high dates.
create or replace temporary table test
(
id number
);

```
insert into test values(1);
insert into test values(2);
insert into test values(3);

alter table test add column start_date date  default -313744;
alter table test add column end_date date  default 2525286;
select * from test;
```

Comment: `alter table test add column start_date date  default -313744;` is incorrect: =>
"Expression type does not match column data type, expecting DATE but got NUMBER(6,0) for column START_DATE"

Comment: In my case i need to set default for existing data, for any new data that i am handling through code.