# Adding default timestamp to a table in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add a new column of timestamp type to a table with default values using following code;

```
ALTER TABLE "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE" ADD COLUMN PRESENT_TIME TIMESTAMPNTZ DEFAULT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC',current_timestamp())::TIMESTAMP_NTZ
```

But this is giving me an error;

> SQL compilation error: Invalid column default expression [CAST(CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_TZ(9))) AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9))]

**Edit**

```
ALTER TABLE "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE" ADD COLUMN PRESENT_TIME TIMESTAMP
DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
```

Error:

> Invalid column default expression [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()]

Can I kindly get help to rectify this error? thanks

Comment: [Snowflake - date constant/literal for ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66788461/snowflake-date-constant-literal-for-alter-table-add-column)

Comment: that makes sense. thanks for sharing it. But do you know why is this failing even without convert_timezone() option?plz see edits above. Help is appreciated.

Comment: As the link mentions, the issue is that you can only use a string literal when using an ALTER command to set a default on a column.  It's not the convert that is doing it, it's the fact that a function is being used.  current_timestamp() is also a function.  I suggest recreating the table with the default attached, rather than altering an existing table.  That will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "DATABASE"."SCHEMA"."TABLE"
   ("ID" INT, "PRESENT_TIME" TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind and helpful advice.

Comment: Will I not lose the data by doing this?

Comment: all data is lost. the table is merely recreated. what's the point of using `create or replace`? the same effect could be achieved by dropping the existing table and creating a new one

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround using update statement:

Create the column_name with timestamp datatype

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name TIMESTAMP_TZ(9);
```

Since the newly create column will be null, you could update it:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as TIMESTAMP_TZ(9)) WHERE column_name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

Giving a tip. Might be helpful seeing you struggle to convert time to utc. You can use sysdate() to get utc time.

Comment: His requirement is to default the value for the timestamp column. Even I want to do the same but I don't want to lose the data in the table. For this, I would need to recreate a table with the same DDL but a different column definition for the timestamp column and then move the data from the original table to this table which I don't want to do.