# snowflake alter an existing table by adding a new timestamp column with default value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake I have tried to alter an existing table by adding a new timestamp column with default value as below.

But none of them worked and did anybody tried this and is this possible in snowflake.

```
ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();

ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT SYSDATE();

ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) DEFAULT CAST(sysdate() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9));

ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT to_timestamp_ntz(current_timestamp)

ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT to_timestamp_ntz('2023-02-20 10:00:00.00000');

ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT '1970-00-00 00:00:00.00000'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ;

ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000';
```

Comment: Seems you hit the same use case [Snowflake - date constant/literal for ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66788461/5070879)

Answer (score 2):

Add defaults only can work if they are constants, as they do not alter the rows.

Your first 4 examples are what you would want (in the real world) but are not fixed value.

the next three while "fixed value" are all aliased to a function call to_timestamp_ntz, and thus a function call, thus not fixed.

and the last example is a text string, thus not a date/timestamp.

Which equates, to you cannot add a default date/timestamp after creating the table.

The solution is to create a new table with this column and your default function. And then insert all the data from the old column, and then swap them.

Comment: Or, alter the table to add the column, and then run an `INSERT OVERWRITE` statement back onto the same table.  This maintains time-travel and load history and avoids the need to swap two tables.

Comment: Great hints, to frame my comment, "just rewrite the table and move on" was focused on the intent, not so much on the optimal way to do it.

Comment: My comment was meant to add to your answer, not correct it.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a default value for a column using alter statement. This is not supported in Snowflake. You will need to create another table with the default value and then load it with data from the existing table. I think the reason why snowflake does not support it is because of the micro partition based architecture. Just imagine, how many micro partitions will need to be created if I allow this alter statement. It will be pretty expensive operation.

Comment: The author wants to add a new column with default which **works**, but not for date/timestamp data type. `CREATE  TABLE t(i INT) AS SELECT 1;` and add new column with default `ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN new_column TEXT DEFAULT 'input';`  -- Statement executed successfully.

Comment: Did not understand the purpose of this comment. You will not be able to add a default through alter...add column.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN new_column TEXT DEFAULT 'input';` is perfectly fine and adds a new column with default attached

Comment: Are you able to do it in an existing table which already has some data. The author is trying to alter an existing table "In snowflake I have tried to alter an existing table "

Comment: Of course: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0w7N.png** - Have you even tried provided code samples?

Comment: The code sample has the default as constant. Try something which is not a constant. Constants are good as they can be part of the metadata, does not need to change micro partitions.

Comment: The whole point of this discussion could be boiled down to two points 1) it is possible to add new column with default but not for every data type 2) `ALTER TABLE TEST.TEST ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000';` even `DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'`  is not accepted as it is treated as expression and not date literal/constant

Comment: Snowflake could jump through hoops, to allow a single level function like "to_date" from a text constant, to be encoded as the constant that is carried on the read to fill in the blanks, but really, you might as well then use a view. But that is gross, and disk is free, so just re-write the table, and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, adding a default value for a column using alter table is not supported.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column

Instead you can create a new table with the default, and insert from the old table, and then swap them

Comment: The author wants to add a new column with default which **works**, but not for date/timestamp data type. `CREATE  TABLE t(i INT) AS SELECT 1;` and add new column with default `ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN new_column TEXT DEFAULT 'input';`  -- Statement executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be:

1. `ALTER TABLE [table] ADD COLUMN LOAD_TIME TIMESTAMP_NTZ NULL;`
2. `UPDATE [table] SET LOAD_TIME = '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'::TIMESTAMP_NTZ WHERE TEST_TIMESTAMP IS NULL;`
3. `ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER LOAD_TIME NOT NULL;`